# What does "refer to their own interest" imply?

Tags: american-english, understanding

I'm decent with the English language but this sentence makes no sense to me.

"Whatever reasons we may have for preserving or protecting non-sentient beings, these reasons do not refer to their own interest.".

So, the reasons are what? I don't understand anything after the comma. An explanation is apreciated.

Comment: What is a non-sentient being, and do they have "interests"?

Comment: A "non-sentient being" is a being that does not have intelligence and self-awareness, like an inanimate object, a plant, a bacterium, etc. Presumably they don't have interests because they do not have any sort of minds to care about their own interests.

Answer (score 2):

If I do something "in my own interest" I am doing it to benefit myself. 
(see this site for more on the phrase: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in-one-s-interest)

So the sentence is saying that people are not protecting the non-sentient beings because they [the beings] have something to gain by being protected [by the people].

Comment: @stangdon you're correct - I misread the sentence, and have edited my response accordingly. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Yes. "We" (whoever "we" are in this context) are not protecting the non-sentient beings for the benefit of the non-sentient beings. I take it the implication is that "we" are protecting them for our own purposes. Like, I don't take care of my car because my car has rights and feelings and deserves to be protected. I take care of my car so that it can better serve me.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, you must first understand that 'their own interest' refers to their own benefit. For example, it is in your own interest to work hard, as you will get paid more (apparently).

The sentence is saying that whatever reasons we have for protecting non-sentient beings, **these reasons are not for their own benefit, but ours.**